# OpenStack machine mounting first volume as /dev/vdc

Tags: centos, devices, block-device, openstack

I have a virtual machine in an internal OpenStack environment. Today, it started misbehaving when a volume is removed and re-attached. In the following, the first two are correct, but the third is not:

```
# initial state
ls /dev/vd*
/dev/vda  /dev/vda1  /dev/vda2  /dev/vdb  /dev/vdb1

# detach volume after it has been unmounted
ls /dev/vd* 
/dev/vda  /dev/vda1  /dev/vda2

# several hours later, re-attach volume
ls /dev/vd*
/dev/vda  /dev/vda1  /dev/vda2  /dev/vdc  /dev/vdc1
```

It should be reattached as /dev/vdb and /dev/vdb1, not /dev/vdc and /dev/vdc1. Because it got attached in the wrong spot, `mount -a` no longer sees it. No other volumes were added or removed during this process. How can I force it to reattach as /dev/vdb?

The dashboard shows that the drive is attached as /dev/vdb.

Comment: Label your volumes and use LABEL= values in `/etc/fstab` so the disks will be found no matter what the `/dev/` entry is.